# re-insert php output into database

Tags: php, mysql

This code provided here are not for production but development, I have a php page out the following:

```
mysql_select_db($database_dd, $dbs);
$query_Getuser = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users, firstname, lastname WHERE status = 'active'",
$Getuser = mysql_query($query_Getuser, $dd) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Getuser = mysql_fetch_assoc($Getuser);
$totalRows_Getuser = mysql_num_rows($Getuser);

if($Getuser){
    // insert my my output values into my new table
}

<table class="table table-responsive">
  <tr>
    <td>User</td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Getuser['username']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Getuser['status']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total Active Users</td>
    <td><?php echo $totalRows_Getuser ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total Inactive Users </td>
    <td><?php echo $totalRows_WScore ?></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

PROBLEM: I tired to capture the output and  have it re-inserted into the a new table I created in my database.
I tried hidden fields but that would require a page a button `isset()` then I taught about using `Session_start()` data like:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['status'] = $_POST['status'];
$_SESSION['totalRows_Getuser'] = $_POST['totalRows_Getuser'];
```

I seem not to be able to get data inserted. What can be done?

Comment: where is your insertion code?

Comment: what are the columns that have in new table ?

Comment: @Noman new table colum username, status, totaluser

Comment: if you can copy the same output by query, would be helpfull ?

Comment: @Noman yes, i want to copy the same output by a query, remember the output is as a result of a query performed...

Comment: ok can you please tell us which table has username,status ? and why did you select `firstname` and `lastname` table in query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with while

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Getuser)){

   .... <?= $row_Getuser['username'] ?>
        <?= $row_Getuser['status'] ?>
```

}

And i would prefer let MySQL count.

```
SELECT COUNT(users) AS ActiveUsers,* FROM users, firstname, lastname WHERE status = 'active'
```

Comment: Muller What I want is how to capture php echo output and have it inserted into a database table of my choice on page loads(i,e php echo output

Answer (score 0):

if both table have same table schema you can use below query

```
INSERT INTO newtable
SELECT * FROM users
```

OR if you want to just copy selected columns data into another table you can use.

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, Country FROM Suppliers
```